# Matplotlib: Convert plot to numpy array without borders

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `scatter()` to produce this plot:

[image]

Then I convert the plot to a numpy array for further processing and get this:

[image]

How can I get rid of the border?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 500
domain_size = 1000

x = np.random.randint(0,domain_size,(n,2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches((5,5))
ax.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c="black", s=200, marker="*")
ax.set_xlim(0,domain_size)
ax.set_ylim(0,domain_size)
fig.add_axes(ax)

fig.canvas.draw()

X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
X = 0.2989*X[:,:,1] + 0.5870*X[:,:,2] + 0.1140*X[:,:,3]

plt.show()
plt.close()

plt.imshow(X, interpolation="none", cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Crop away the borders using a slice, or set xlim and ylim on the `imshow` plot...

Comment: @NilsWerner For further processing I need a numpy array without white borders. Cropping away the borders is not a clean solution, since the size of the borders depends on `fig.set_size_inches(())`. Setting `xlim` or `ylim` has no effects on `X` and therefore does not solve my problem. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get rid of the borders. Just replace

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
```

with

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.,0.,1.,1.])
```

and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should turn off the `axis` each time before rendering the plots. Here is the modified code that does so.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 500
domain_size = 100
x = np.random.randint(0,domain_size,(n,2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches((5,5))
ax.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c="black", s=200, marker="*")
ax.set_xlim(0,domain_size)
ax.set_ylim(0,domain_size)
ax.axis('off')

fig.add_axes(ax)
fig.canvas.draw()

# this rasterized the figure
X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
X = 0.2989*X[:,:,1] + 0.5870*X[:,:,2] + 0.1140*X[:,:,3]

plt.show()
plt.close()

# plot the image array X
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(X, interpolation="none", cmap="gray")

ax2.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: The border is still there when I use your code. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean `white border`?

Comment: Yes, when I use your code, I still get a white border. Any suggestion how to remove it without using a slice?